# extract certain values from a JSON File (python)

Tags: python, json

Im getting a response from a request to my power plug that looks like this:

```
{"emeter":{"get_realtime":{"voltage_mv":235176,"current_ma":12,"power_mw":0,"total_wh":4525,"err_code":0}}}
```

Which I saved to the variable `response`

Now I want it to just give me the value of "current_ma" when I am sending the  request.
How can I achieve this?

I tried something like `response.current_ma`, but that just gives me errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
current_ma = response["emeter"]["get_realtime"]["current_ma"]
print("Antwort: {}".format(response["emeter"]["get_realtime"]["current_ma"]))
```

Comment: Thank you, but with this code I am getting the error: "Type Error: String indices must be integers"

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: sure: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Michi/Desktop/Nodejs_NodeRed/TestProject/tpLinkBlog.py", line 47, in <module>
    print("Antwort: " + response["emeter"]["get_realtime"]["current_ma"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: The problem is regarding printing this output. I have updated the post. Please verify it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your new post. But unfortunately it didnt change anything. The message im getting now is: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tpLinkBlog.py", line 50, in <module>
    print("Antwort: {}".format(response["emeter"]["get_realtime"]["current_ma"]))
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
response["emeter"]["get_realtime"]["current_ma"]
```

JSON is like a tree structure, where you need to reference the levels in the tree to where the data you are fetching is located.

I believe its good practice to wrap this in a try, in case the value is not present. Like this:

```
try:
   my_var = response["emeter"]["get_realtime"]["current_ma"]
except KeyError as ex:
   # do something useful if exception is thrown
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but im now getting this error: 
"TypeError: string indices must be integers"
 
Im trying to figure out how this can be solved

Comment: I would suggest you read a bit about how to work with JSON in Python. This is a good place to start: https://realpython.com/python-json/